# Font Size on HTML

Tags: html, fonts

I am building a web application that displays the content of an actual real-life book as static HTML pages.

Is there any possibility to add a feature to allow the user to change the font size from the application(not by changing it in the CSS).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you have to do is bind the value of `style` attribute to be able to control it dynamically.

Here is a working example on the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nakhodkiin/6r9pc5h0/5/)

#### HTML

```html
<h2>Change text-size</h2>
<div>
  <input id="range" type="range">
</div>
<div id="div">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At dicta id impedit laudantium accusantium hic quisquam asperiores cumque dolores explicabo commodi amet suscipit dolorum, debitis provident vitae excepturi officia, illum, perferendis? Expedita repellendus atque consequuntur dolorum. Provident ipsam consequuntur nisi quas excepturi earum vero, dolores ut ab maiores quod accusamus? Dicta labore eos vel non, accusamus, facere molestiae dolores doloremque at aspernatur id, temporibus quidem natus eveniet! Ex repellat libero tempore, sit nisi explicabo, illum animi unde officia totam quibusdam nesciunt possimus rerum cumque incidunt corporis facere dolore harum ipsam aperiam amet quidem adipisci vero cum! Nostrum, sit tempore dignissimos!
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
const div = document.getElementById('div');
const rangeInput = document.getElementById('range');

rangeInput.oninput = e => {
    div.style.fontSize = e.target.value + 'px'
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfectly! Thank you!